# How to add the content of a uploaded task (a file .pdf for example) in XML-RPC

Tags: xml, xml-rpc

I've already written the following code:

```
<methodCall>
  <methodName> UPLOAD </methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value><string> Task 2 </string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string> Group 1 </string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

I still have to add the content of an exercise or a file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `<base64>` element to send binary data, encoded in Base64. Check the [XML-RPC specification](http://xmlrpc.com/spec.md#scalar-values):

> | Tag | Type | Example |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | `<base64>` | base64-encoded binary | eW91IGNhbid0IHJlYWQgdGhpcyE= |

Comment: Like this:

```<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  
<methodName> UPLOAD </methodName>
  <params>
      <base><base64-encoded> file </base64-encoded>
      </base>
    <param>
      <value><string> task 2 </string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string> group 1 </string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>```

Comment: No, the type of the element is `<base64>`. It is not `<base>` or  `<base-encoded>`.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName> HOCHLADEN </methodName>
  <params>
      <base64> file </base64>
    <param>
      <value><string> Übung 2 </string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string> Gruppe 1 </string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>`



is there a `<param> </param>` missing?

Comment: It should be like this i guess:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName> HOCHLADEN </methodName>
  <params>
    <param><value><base64> file </base64></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string> Übung 2 </string></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value><string> Gruppe 1 </string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>`